# extracting links from a website

Tags: python

So I want to go to http://www.medhelp.org/forums/list and then there are lots of links to different diseases there. Inside each link, there are several pages each one has some links again that I want.

I want to get some of the links. so I used this code:

```
myArray=[]
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.medhelp.org/forums/list")
soup = bs(html_page)
temp =soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class' : 'forums_link'})
for div in temp:
  myArray.append('http://www.medhelp.org' + div.a['href'])
myArray_for_questions=[]
myPages=[]

#this for is going over all links on the main page. in this case, all 
diseases
for link in myArray:

  # "link" is the URL for each link in the main page of our website
  html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
  soup1 = bs(html_page)

  #getting the questions's links in the first page
  temp =soup1.findAll('div',attrs={'class' : 'subject_summary'}) 
  for div in temp:
     myArray_for_questions.append('http://www.medhelp.org' + div.a['href'])

  #now getting the URL for all next pages for this page
  pages = soup1.findAll('a' ,href=True, attrs={'class' : 'page_nav'})
  for l in pages:
    html_page_t = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.medhelp.org' 
    +l.get('href'))
    soup_t = bs(html_page_t)
    other_pages = soup_t.findAll('a' ,href=True, attrs={'class' : 
    'page_nav'})
    for p in other_pages:
        mystr='http://www.medhelp.org' +p.get('href')   
        if mystr not in myPages:
            myPages.append(mystr)
        if p not in pages:
            pages.append(p)

  # getting all links inside this page which are people's questions
  for page in myPages:
      html_page1 = urllib.request.urlopen(page)
      soup2 = bs(html_page1)
      temp =soup2.findAll('div',attrs={'class' : 'subject_summary'}) 
      for div in temp:
        myArray_for_questions.append('http://www.medhelp.org' + 
        div.a['href'])
```

but it takes forever to get all links I want from all pages. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is too generic. 
Please tell us what you have tried so far and narrow down your question.

Comment: When asking a question, You usually want to have code that you've tried to implement and have a question about, or you should ask for help understanding code that you've found through research on the topic ( with example snippets).

Comment: I have not started yet. I just wanna write a special web crawler I think to do that because there are lots of questions asked in this forum about different diseases that I need all of them to be saved in a file.

Comment: You should do some research on the topic first. This will help you ask a good question. I would suggest simply googling "Python web crawler". There are several frameworks that make this easy and simple.

Comment: I did some research over it but not found something useful except for BeautifulSoup that might help me but not know how to use it.

Comment: *Can anyone help me?*: yes we can! But you have to start the job, write some code and explain where you are stuck. [ask] is a good starting point. Currently your question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the scrapy tutorial, follow it trying to replace the example provided with your web page:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html